# Spring data commons 2.7.3 doesn't update when using save()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I have recently upgraded my project to java 17 and spring boot 2.7.4 and spring cloud 2021.0.4. I am using mavenBom for spring cloud dependency management. It has brought in spring-data-commons-2.7.3.

With the upgrade, the CRUD repository's save() doesn't seem to be updating the existing objects. I am getting a duplicate key exception.  (`org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Document with the given id already exists`).
I have already tried enabling transaction management, but to no avail.

Could you please help.

Comment: This is getting looked on git issues  of spring data framework - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1658

Answer (score 2):

auto-upsert is not supported by spring-data-couchbase v 4.4.3.

If you want to use upsert() on an entiy class that has an @Version property, you'll need to explicitly use template.upsertById() or introduce your own repository.upsert() method. Or override the repository.save() method.